# Multiple model binding to list of object in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can you tell me how to select multiple rows with many different id in a table and store it into ViewBag?

This line can get all rows with the id is "123": `ViewBag.Name = (from m in myDatabase.myTable where m.id == "123" select m).ToList();`

Calling it in View:

```
<tr>
foreach(var item in ViewBag.Name)
{
   <td>@item.ProductName</td>
   <td>@item.Category</td>
}
</tr>
```

Now. I have a list to store the values of the id. Like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("123");
list.Add("456");
list.Add("789");
//.....
```

And an un-complete loop:

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
   // ViewBag.Name = from m in myDatabase.myTable where ..........
}
```

Please help!

Comment: First, don't use `ViewBag`.

Comment: Try `from m in myDatabase.myTable where list.Contains(m.id) select m`.

Comment: This is so wrong on so many levels. Basically i think you want something like `ViewBag.Names = (from m in myDatabase.myTable where m.id == "123" || m.id == "456" || m.id == "789" select m.Name).ToList();`

Comment: And how can you keep a list of entities in a Name var ? Wow... wait.. WHAT?

Comment: Complaining about variable names in samples then providing an example with an obviously variable list *hardcoded*... wow...wait...what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `List` with `HashSet` (small optimization):

```
HashSet<string> list = new HashSet<string>();
list.Add("123");
list.Add("456");
list.Add("789");
// ...
```

Query:

```
ViewBag.Name = (from m in myDatabase.myTable
                where list.Contains(m.id)
                select m).ToList();
```

Add model to view, and put result in model, not in `ViewBag`.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewBag.Name` is a dynamic type which is getting assigned to `List<myTable>`

You can use `FirstOrDefault` to find the item in the existing list.

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    var name = ViewBag.Name.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == item);
    if (name != null) 
    {
       <td>@name.ProductName</td>
       <td>@name.Category</td> 
    }
}
```

Couple of points:

- `ViewBag.Name` would be better named for what it is, eg `ViewBag.MyTableList` or even just plural `ViewBag.Names`
- you might find model binding easier if you use a strongly defined viewmodel, rather than `ViewBag`
- depending on how many rows there are, you could make this more efficient

It's hard to tell where `ViewBag.Name` and `list` are being set.  If these are both in the codebehind, then you could filter the data selection rather than filter on the UI - this would be more efficient.